# Possible to setup SQL Managment Studio to show multiline fields when viewing multiline data?

Tags: sql-server

Normally it just puts multiline content on a one liner field and adds slightly smaller than normal tabs between text where the line breaks would normally be.

I am using SQL Management Studio Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only option is to choose Results to Text instead of Results to Grid. Even then, the new lines will wrap to the beginning of the entire data line, so it's not much of an improvement.